# Terraform multiple s3 bucket creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, bucket

I am trying to create multiple s3 buckets each with different bucket settings. i am Looking for syntax on how to refer the bucket ids of the dynamically created bucket in other bucket resource blocks.
New to terraform. looking for sample code or terrraform document for this syntax

Bel0w is sample code for creating bucket from list names

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  count=length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket = var.bucket_names[count.index]
  acl="private"

  versioning {
    enabled = var.bucket_versioning
  }
}
```

In this code i want to refer the dynamically created bucket id's and assign their bucket policy settings. Need the syntax . not sure if this correct

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "this" {
  count=length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id[count.index]
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `aws_s3_bucket_policy`, instead of

```
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id[count.index]
```

it should be

```
bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this[count.index].id
```

assuming that everything else is correct, e.g. `data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json` is valid.

Comment: Thanks. Will try with this change. Also, this the code for  ```data.aws_iam_policy_document.this.json```     is this correct?  i am referring to the index here for each bucket name in policy                                 
 ```data "aws_iam_policy_document" "this" {
  count=length(var.bucket_names)
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = var.bucket_roles
    }

    actions = var.bucket_actions

    resources = [
      aws_s3_bucket.this[count.index],
      "${aws_s3_bucket.this[count.index].arn}/*"
    ]
  }
} ```

Comment: @CharlesD Since `aws_iam_policy_document` uses count, in `aws_s3_bucket_policy` you also need to use index, e.g., `policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.this[count.index].json`.

Comment: Thanks. For now, i am using single policy for all buckets. Yes, will modify when i use different policy like u pointed out.  i was checking with you on this code where we refer bucket naame in policy ```resources = [       aws_s3_bucket.this[count.index],       "${aws_s3_bucket.this[count.index].arn}/*" ``` the index reference syntax there . hope this syntax is fine. Thank U